# Minimize absolute values of errors instead of squares

Tags: optimization

Calculating absolute values is much more efficient than calculating squares. Is there any advantage, then, to using the latter as a cost function over the former? Squares are easier to treat analytically, but in practice that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what term "calculating absolute values is much more efficient than calculating squares"? Compared to the complexity of any estimator/model used, I don't think it is significant - but I would be interested if anyone makes me wrong.

Again, why do you think it doesn't matter in practice? Working with a smooth and convex function is more convenient (in terms of time and results) than not-convex function.

Actually, you can choose whatever function to minimize you'd like; it is just a trade-off between :

- Which kind of value you want to penalize
- Complexity of the function to solve (mathematically speaking : local or global solution)
- Time consuming (related to the previous point)

**1. Minimizing absolute values** :

With absolute value, you penalize the distance between *y* and *f(x)* linearly. Roughly speaking, you might end up with a lot of data that will look like outliers as long as *enough* are well explained by your estimator *f*.

Then, to minimize a function, one generally looks for the root(s) of its derivative. However, the derivative of *|x|* is not smooth. You can work with subgradient and other more complex mathematical object that may result in a longer time process due to more calculation.

**2. Minimizing square values** :

In this case, the distance between *y* and *f(x)* is more penalized. You'll tend to have less *outliers* (relatively to *f(x)*).

What is interesting is that is a smooth function (i.e. a defined derivative) and convex (with a global minimum)

So I guess people believe that the square of errors is a good trade-off.

Answer (score 2):

**Both the square and the absolute value should work okay for gradient descent but the square will work better.  For calculus based methods, the absolute value method may be intractable.**

If you are using gradient descent methods then the square works very nicely in that it tends to form a U shape which takes big steps away from the minimum and smaller steps close to the minimum. Conversely, absolute values tend to form V shapes which take roughly the same step size. The result is that squares have better convergence properties.

Now, calculus based methods tend to take the derivative of a function and set it equal to zero.  Notice that U shapes tend to have well defined derivatives equal to zero at the minima, which works perfectly. By contrast, the V shape has an undefined derivative at its minima which tend to make conjugate gradient methods un-invertible.

Hope this helps!